# Question involving approximation, taylor series and proving

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, fractions

**Question:**
Consider the approximation $$\ln(2)\approx 2\left ( \frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3\times 3^{3}}+\frac{1}{5\times 3^{5}} \right )$$

Prove that the error in this approximation is less than $$\frac{1}{7\times 2^{2} \times 3^{5}}$$
**Attempt:**
It looks like the expression comes from the taylor series expansion so:
$\ln(1+x)=x-\frac{x^{2}}{2}+\frac{x^{3}}{3}-\frac{x^{4}}{4}+... \text{ for }\ -1< x< 1$

$\ln(1-x)=-x-\frac{x^{2}}{2}-\frac{x^{3}}{3}-\frac{x^{4}}{4}+...$

$\therefore \ln\left ( \frac{1+x}{1-x} \right )=2\left ( x+\frac{x^{3}}{3}+\frac{x^{5}}{5}+\frac{x^{7}}{7} \right )$

$\text{Now let}\ x=\frac{1}{3}$

$\therefore \ln(2)=2\left ( \frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3\times 3^{3}}+\frac{1}{5\times 3^{5}}+\frac{1}{7\times 3^{7}}\right )$

So we have to prove that:

$2\left (\frac{1}{7\times 3^{7}}+\frac{1}{9\times 3^{9}}+\frac{1}{11\times 3^{11}}\cdots\right) < \frac{1}{7\times 2^{2} \times 3^{5}}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can say that $2\left (\frac{1}{7\times 3^{7}}+\frac{1}{9\times 3^{9}}+\frac{1}{11\times 3^{11}}\cdots\right)<2 \left (\frac{1}{7\times 3^{7}}+\frac{1}{7\times 3^{9}}+\frac{1}{7\times 3^{11}}\cdots\right)= 2 \left(\frac{1}{7\times 3^7}\right)
\div \left(1-\frac{1}{3^2}\right)=\frac{1}{7\times 2^2\times3^5}$

Answer (score 4):

Since $9\gt 7$, and $11\gt 7$, and $13\gt 7$, and so on, the tail 
$$\frac{2}{7\cdot 3^7}+\frac{2}{9\cdot 3^9}+\frac{2}{11\cdot 3^{11}}+\frac{2}{13\cdot 3^{13}}+\cdots$$
is less than the sum of the geometric series 
$$\frac{2}{7\cdot 3^7}\left(1+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{3^4}+\frac{1}{3^6}+\cdots\right).$$
But 
$$1+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{3^4}+\frac{1}{3^6}+\cdots=\frac{9}{8}.$$

Comment: You are welcome. When we have an alternating series, estimating tails is easy. But in power series with positive terms, bounding by a geometric series is the usual approach.